# error TF30073: trying to create workspace for TFS 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

After 2 weeks of testing and all was good, we all of a sudden get this;

when i try to:
_workspace = CreateWorkSpace("some name", _vcs.AuthorizedUser)

Ik get this error:
TF30073: Please contact your administrator. There was an error processing your request.Technical information (for admininstrator): Sql error: 2627.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted some forgotten workspaces for that user (serviceaccount tfs) and all is well again!